How do I create an 'Update Profile Picture' function in django
Okay, so basically I created a function in django where you can change the profile picture but the issue is that It's doing something else instead. Have a look below to understand what's happening
I have added these codes into my settings.py file
settings.py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')


and also added these to the urls.py
urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path , include 
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('user/',include('members.urls')),
    path('',include('blogposts.urls')), # MAIN URL 
    
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

This is the model that I created for the User
models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete = models.CASCADE, null = True , blank = True )
    bio = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'images',default= '/../media/images/image.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

This is the form that I created to change the Profile Pic
forms.py
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile 
        fields = ['profile_pic']

This is the urls.py inside the app
urls.py (app)
from django.urls import path , include 
from . import views 


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.homepage,name = 'home-page'),
    path('view_post/<int:pk>',views.view_post,name='view-post'),
    path('blogcreation',views.create_blog,name='blog-form'),

    path('aboutme',views.about_user,name = 'show-user'), # this is the one that takes to the page where you can change your profile picture and displays your bio

    path('delete/<int:pk>',views.delete_post,name = 'delete-post'),
    path('edit_blog/<int:pk>',views.edit_blog,name = 'edit-post'),
]


These are the codes in views.py
views.py
def about_user(request):

    profile = Profile.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'show_user.html',{'form':form,'profile':profile})

    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'show_user.html',{'form':form,'profile':profile})


and finally. This is show_user.html my html page.
show_user.html
{{user.profile.bio}}
<img src = "{{user.profile.profile_pic}}" height = "500">



<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>




and these are my directories.

Now the issue is that my user profile bio is working fine and my default user profile is showing.

But when I want to change the pic and click on 'choose file' and choose a random pic which is located in my media folder

after selecting 'download.jpg' and uploading it. It doesn't change the picture and this is what happens.

any solutions ?
I cannot wrap my head around this and I can't find any solutions.

When you create the form, Django doesn't know you want to update an existing Profile, so it creates a new one, which is what's causing the problem.  What you can do is supply the form with the instance you are trying to update, then Django will automatically update the instance.  First you need to get the instance you are trying to update, then add that instance to the form.
# views.py

def about_user(request):

    profile = Profile.objects.all()
    
    # get the instance of the Profile you are trying to update
    profile_instance = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if request.method == "POST":

        # Add that instance to the form, so Django knows which instance to update
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=profile_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'show_user.html',{'form':form,'profile':profile})

    else:
        form = ProfileForm()

    return render(request, 'show_user.html',{'form':form,'profile':profile})


Sorry to say but not working. I forgot to mention that my default image and the image that I am going to add are in the same directory if anything related to that is an issue ? because the error when I try to upload the file download.png, Its giving me the error in the terminal - Not Found: /images/download_A7XfHLd.jpg
